# In C++, why doesn't the copy of a constant also have to be a constant when I pass it by value?

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-value

For example, this code compiles (g++ 13.1.0) and gives me output "Sum is 20":

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void add (int x, int y, int sum);

int main(){
    int x = 10, y = 10;
    const int sum = 0;

    add (x, y, sum);

    return 0;
}

void add (int x, int y, int sum) {
    sum = x + y;
    cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;
}
```

I expected the compiler to complain about either trying to pass a constant value to something that's treated as non-constant within the function, or failing to declare `sum` as constant in `add`. I think I understand everything that's happening here - I'm creating a non-constant copy of a constant variable. I'm just curious why this kind of behavior is permitted.

Comment: you created a *copy*, that copy is not const, so you can modify that non constant copy all you want. That wont ever change the source.

Comment: The caller's **arguments** are *copied* into the function's **parameters**.  Those parameters are *local* to the function.

Comment: RIght.  If you had written `int & sum`, then you would have had a compile-time error, because you'd be trying to pass the actual `sum` variable, not the VALUE of `sum`.

Comment: If I tell you you can't write on a piece of paper and then you photocopy it and write on the copy, you've still done what I asked.

Comment: Side issue: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: "*I'm just curious why this kind of behavior is permitted."* -- Why wouldn't it be? I mean, it's not uncommon, if using paper, to have a blank "master" form that gets copied, and the copies are filled in. The master is read-only / `const` and the copies are **intended** to be written on. Intuition is based on the real world. Do you have an example of a real-world scenario where it makes sense that copying should preserve a "don't change this" restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I understand everything that's happening here - I'm creating a non-constant copy of a constant variable.

No and no.

You're copying/assigning the value of a constant variable into a non-constant variable, which is totally ok, e.g.

```
const int c = 0; //constant variable, define/initialize it
                 //with the value 0
int i = c; //declare non-constant variable and define/initialize it
           //with the value of c

//or

int i; //declare only
i = c; //assign/copy value of c to i
```

Even this is valid

```
int i = 0;
const int c = i;

//but

i = 42; //ok
c = 42; //not ok, c is read only
```

Passing arguments by value to a function is not indifferent to declaring a variable and assigning a value to it. The function argument is local to the function and if it is declared as non const, it can be freely modified.

e.g.

```
void foo(int sum)
{
    sum = 42; //ok, sum is a local non constant variable
}

const int c = 0;
foo(c); //assign/copy the value of c to the variable sum, same as:
        //int sum = c;
```

but

```
void foo(const int sum)
{
    sum = 42; //not ok, sum is a local constant variable, 
              //read only -> not modifiable
    //but
    int i = sum;
    i += 1; //ok, i is modified not sum
}

int i = 0;
foo(i); //ok, assign/copy the value of i to the variable sum, same as:
        //const int sum = i;

const int c = 0;
foo(c); //ok, assign/copy the value of c to the variable sum, same as:
        //const int sum = c;
```

**In short:** the `const` type qualifier is a promise to the compiler, that once the variable is initialized to never be modified again. And the compiler will let you know (via error) if you do so. But once copied into other variables, there might be no promise for those regions of memory (if non const).

Answer (score 0):

> In C++, why doesn't the copy of a constant also have to be a constant when I pass it by value?

Because in C++ whether an variable is const or not is **determined when declaring/defining that variable.**

In particular, when you wrote `int x` you're specifically saying that you don't want `x` to be a const. If you wanted `x` to be a const, then the declaration would include a const as in `const int x`.